# lint-staged not running on precommit

Tags: javascript, git, pre-commit-hook, prettier, lint-staged

prettier is not running on precommit. This worked with the same configuration in other projects, so I'm baffled why it's not working this time.

This is the relevant section of my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
  },
"lint-staged": {
  "*.{js,json,css,scss,html,md}": [
    "prettier --write",
    "git add"
  ]
},
```

Edit. Here are the relevant devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "husky": "^0.14.3",
  "lint-staged": "^7.0.4",
  "prettier": "1.12.0"
},
```

Comment: The configuration must be indeed different as it is not going to work but to help, we need more information. Do you have some error messages/logs? Is prettier installed properly on current project? Does `git add` work properly instead?

Comment: Do you have husky installed? https://github.com/typicode/husky
How about option 5? https://prettier.io/docs/en/precommit.html

Comment: @mpasko256 Yes, I have husky installed. No error messages popping up. Prettier is installed properly. I will paste the relevant section of devDependencies

Comment: @mpasko256 option 5 is a bit confusing... How would I make it work for files other than js files?

Comment: I meant to try out option 5 only for test purposes. But to make it less confusing for you: it simply queries git for changed files and saves result in $jsfiles variable. You can just change ```"*.js" "*.jsx"``` into ```"*.js" "*.json" "*.css" "*.scss" "*.html" "*.md"``` to make it work for your example.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Reinstalled husky and now seems to be working. Thanks @mpasko256 for your help!

Comment: I think this trick is not working these days, I have done this by clearing my cache but did not worked

Answer (score 101):

I tried so many solutions on here but a combination finally worked!

1. Make sure Husky v4 is installed. v6 was never triggering for me.
2. Check the output of `git config core.hooksPath`. This should *not* return anything. If it does run,

```
git config --unset core.hookspath
```

And FINALLY it worked!

Comment: Yes, this works. I had downgraded from husky 5 to 4. But v4 was not working - although the same setup worked in another project. This solution was the missing step.

Comment: I can't believe it, it works so well, thank you so much My husky 3.0.4

Comment: it really worked.. any explanation why it worked?

Comment: Really nice man. Kudos!

Comment: Thanks @JoãoIgnacio – but I'm not a man. :')

Comment: So sorry @SwaathiKakarla! Thank you ma'am!

Comment: This now even works with husky@7.0.4 for me! NICE

Comment: I had been trying to fix this for a couple of hours, thanks!

Comment: This only removes the hook which is basically disabling husky. Only reason it works for people is because it no longer runs the precommit

Answer (score 96):

**In 2021**

Sometimes hooks are not added by `husky` so you need to add it using a simple easy hack.

You need to uninstall husky first after that install `V4` of husky because it ensures that your hooks are correctly installed and after that install the latest version of `husky` so you get the latest updates.

**NPM**

```
npm uninstall husky

npm install -D husky@4

npm install -D husky
```

**YARN**

```
yarn remove husky

yarn add -D husky@4

yarn add -D husky
```

If sometimes above trick not works, so let's add the hook into husky, below mention method is used only in `V6` and I am showing the `husky` with `lint-staged` example.

**NPM**

```
npm install -D husky

npm set-script prepare "husky install" && npm run prepare

npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "npx lint-staged"

git commit -m "added husky and lint-stagged" // here you will notice the lint-staged checking the files with help of husky
```

**YARN**

```
yarn add -D husky

npm set-script prepare "husky install" && yarn prepare

npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "yarn lint-staged"

git commit -m "added husky and lint-stagged" // here you will notice the lint-staged checking the files with help of husky
```

Comment: As @Geoff mentioned in below answer, hooks aren't automatically installed
using `husky@4`, pre-commit hooks work. This should be the current accepted answer

Comment: for `npm set-script prepare` I get `sh: husky: command not found` -- do you have it installed as a global?

Comment: no, it will automatically be stored in the `.bin` folder and it will execute from there.

Comment: Ah, husky 4 won't work for that, that was the issue. Been downgrading to 4 and then installing 7 to try and sort out these issues. Had 4 installed.

Comment: I tried and it is working on my system and I didn't install the global package, are you using linux?

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 44):

The problem for me was I ran "**npx mrm lint-staged**" like the official website says but it only set the **husky** and **lint-staged** configurations in package.json. It does not add then as dependency or installed them.

The solution for me was:

1. `npm i -D husky lint-staged`
2. `npx mrm lint-staged`

Comment: Saved my day! Ran `npx mrm lint-staged` then the hooks worked like a charm.

Answer (score 30):

For me the issue was resolved by uninstalling and installing lower version

```
npm uninstall husky

npm install -D husky@4          //after this it will work
```

Comment: Yep, same thing happened to me and this solution works.

Comment: Reason why this works is that husky versions after 4 stopped installing git hooks automatically. They put up instructions how to add those here github.com/typicode/husky

Answer (score 26):

Probably your husky package already in your `node_modules` before you configured this script. Try to reinstall the hooks, you can run:

```sh
npm rebuild
```

Or if [you're using yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2069#issuecomment-417184001):

```sh
npm rebuild --update-binary
```

It solved my problem.

Comment: Surprised to see an answer so recent. I think my machine was in a funk and I had the problem OP had. Thanks for the answer, it seemed to do the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: Aha, I just got a similar issue recently, thank you as well!

Comment: thank you. yarn rebuild is has not been found in my system, so needed just to yarn remove husky && yarn add --dev husky

Comment: ▶ yarn rebuild
yarn run v1.3.2
(node:99635) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
error Command "rebuild" not found.

Comment: it fixed my issue

Comment: `yarn rebuild` isn't a command (or at least it's not anymore). See: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2069

Answer (score 17):

You are missing dependencies:

```
npm install --save-dev prettier husky lint-staged
```

Comment: Hey I had already installed lint-staged and prettier however I did not installed husky since i thought I am not using it so why to install. But I am not sure the moment I just installed husky lint-staged started working Thanks. !

Answer (score 13):

For anyone with this problem and using Husky 5, the hooks aren't automatically installed. So you probably just don't have the required hooks in your `.git/hooks folder` at all. You need to either add a `postinstall` to your package.json (recommended), or run `npx husky install` after you've npm installed the package.

[image]

Or just downgrade to Husky 4. You'll actually have to do this, if, like me, you're working on a commercial project and don't want to be a Husky sponsor.

[image]

https://dev.to/typicode/what-s-new-in-husky-5-32g5

Answer (score 13):

Wasted hours in figuring out the cause and using the solutions above

**Read the documentation and avoid googling**:
https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=automatic-recommended

**Or follow the steps below:**

> husky-init is a one-time command to quickly initialize a project with husky.

```
npx husky-init && npm install       # npm
npx husky-init && yarn              # Yarn 1
yarn dlx husky-init --yarn2 && yarn # Yarn 2
```

Answer (score 8):

**I think there was something wrong with your `package.json`.**

```
"scripts":{
   ...
},
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
        "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
        "pre-push": "npm test"
    }
},
"lint-staged": {
    "*.ts": ["tslint", "prettier --write", "git add"]
}
```

By the way, after installed `husky`, just check `.git/hooks/pre-commit` content. If no `husky` like word in it, just remove the `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file and reinstall `husky` or run `npx husky`. Because `husky` will skip modifying the `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file if it is not `GHook` alike or `PreCommit` alike.

You may find it out by following this link.
https://github.com/typicode/husky/blob/master/src/installer/hooks.ts#L58

**One alternative is to use `pre-commit`.**

```
yarn add --dev pre-commit
```

```
"scripts":{
   ...
},
"pre-commit":"lint-staged",
...
```

Answer (score 6):

For me the problem was that the `pre-commit` hook was not executable which was easily fixed:

```
chmod +x .husky/pre-commit
```

Answer (score 5):

This was happening to me and none of these answers helped. So for future reference, it was because I was using `npm@7` which [looks like it doesn't know how to properly execute husky](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1845).

The way I found out it was a problem with husky and npm was because I found out that I had no `pre-commit` file inside `my-project/.git/hooks` directory.

When you install husky, it automatically do its magic for you in such folder. So for that, I had to:

1. Downgrade to `npm i -g npm@6`
2. Be sure everything was freshly reinstalled with `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm i` (you should see Husky output in the console)
3. And although it isn't really needed, I executed again `npx mrm lint-staged`

Finally, it worked.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. What helped me was the 2nd and 3rd step and did not need to downgrade my NPM.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem by adding `yarn` at the beginning of commands.
*(husky v6)*

*.husky/pre-commit*

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

yarn lint-staged
```

*.husky/commit-msg*

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

yarn commitlint -e $HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks. this one work for me

```
npm install -D husky
npm set-script prepare "husky install" && npm run prepare
npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "npx lint-staged"
git commit -m "added husky and lint-stagged"
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for us: (for some reason this was not mentioned in other solutions)

```
npx husky install
```

**Situation:**

Husky pre-commit hook was configured and worked for some time. We missed the exact moment then it stopped triggering, but supposedly it is related to one of Husky's updates.

Running command

```
git config core.hooksPath
```

returned nothing.

After running the command mentioned above, the same git config command returned

```
.husky
```

Husky version 8.0.3, hope this helps anybody!

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps someone else: another thing to try is to delete your `node_modules` folder and rerun `npm install`

I originally ran `npm install` in the linux subsystem on my Windows 10 machine.  Everything worked fine using git through bash.  I received the error after switching over to git in 
 Powershell.  Uninstalling and reinstalling prettier, husky, and lint-staged did not work for me.

I deleted my node_modules folder and reran `npm install` from the Windows side and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

For **windows users**, simply do the following in command line/bash:

```
set HUSKY_DEBUG = 1
```

or

```
set HUSKY_DEBUG = true
```

This solved , my hours of head scratching. 
Also see [this](https://vision.middlebury.edu/~tdorjee/node_modules/husky/DOCS.md)

Answer (score 2):

To follow @typicode's message [here](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/618#issuecomment-571407578):

> I suspect it's because npm run modifies PATH to include node_modules/.bin. On the other side, when hook commands are run PATH isn't modified.

If you change your .husky/pre-commit to include this path, it works with husky@latest:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

node_modules/.bin/lint-staged
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in my case was that there were some existing hooks and `husky` does not override them (more info [here](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/171)).

Just putting it here in case someone else runs into the same issue.

Comment: It does, for me.

Answer (score 1):

The `git add` command is no longer required in the lint-stage v10 onwards. It is automatically inserted to the commit as the docs describe it:

> From v10.0.0 onwards any new modifications to originally staged files will be automatically added to the commit. If your task previously contained a git add step, please remove this. The automatic behaviour ensures there are less race-conditions, since trying to run multiple git operations at the same time usually results in an error.

https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#configuration

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest husky version, make sure to install the hook after you add it. In husky 4, this was done automatically.

```
npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "lint-staged; git add ."
husky install .husky
```

This solved issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I did this mistake.

I have added `lint-staged` object inside `husky` object, but later realized I need to add `lint-staged` key-value pairs as direct key-value pairs in `package.json`

```
"lint-staged": {
  "*.{js,json,css,scss,html,md}": [
    "prettier --write",
    "git add"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to the node version you are using. Husky requires node >= 10 and lint-staged requires node >= 10.13

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed husky

add the below scripts to package.json script

```
"prepare": "husky install && npx husky add .husky/pre-commit \"npm run lint-fix\"",
"lint": "eslint ./",
"lint-fix": "eslint ./ --fix"
```

you scripts will be looking something like this

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "prepare": "husky install && npx husky add .husky/pre-commit \"npm run lint-fix\"",
    "lint": "eslint ./",
    "lint-fix": "eslint ./ --fix",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\""
  },
```

run the following command

```
npm run prepare
```

this script will create a .husky folder to your working directory and adds pre-commit file to it with script npm run lint-fix to it.

congrats ... now you can commit your files and see precommit checks your eslint error if any

you can add below line to your .git ignore file

```
/.husky
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [pre-commit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-commit) library. You don't have to configure any thing, It works like charm.

How to use ⬇️

```
{
  "name": "437464d0899504fb6b7b",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "ERROR: No README.md file found!",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: I SHOULD FAIL LOLOLOLOLOL \" && exit 1",
    "foo": "echo \"fooo\" && exit 0",
    "bar": "echo \"bar\" && exit 0"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "test"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that `lint-staged` is actually running but your files have no lint errors at all. If your files only have warnings, the `pre-commit` hook will not do anything and lets you commit. So make sure you actually have lint errors.

I know it's not exactly an answer to the question, but there are already lots of great answers and this can also be a cause that can be easily overlooked. (Heard it from a friend )

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that i forgot to add pre-commit file in the .husky directory (.husky/pre-commit)

its content might be something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

# Run lint-staged
npx lint-staged
```

Answer (score -1):

### Breaking changes

Be aware that there were breaking changes in the `5x >` version.

If you're struggling to get it working, here's how I got `Husky`(v6) working with `lint-staged`.

**Assuming that you already have it installed** otherwise skip to step number 3.

1 - `yarn remove husky`

2 - `yarn add -D husky`

3 - `husky install`

4 - `husky add .husky/pre-commit "pre-comit"`

5 - `chmod a+x .husky/pre-commit`

6 - In the **package.json** add the following script `"pre-commit": "lint-staged"`

7 - Add your **lint-staged** configuration e.g

```
...
"lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
      "prettier --write"
  ]
}
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem for another reason. Just had the HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Command Processor \ AutoRun set to cd \python. After deleting this "AutoRun", lint-staged is running on precommit without any errors.