# husk does not execute the precommit while I commit new files

Tags: javascript, prettier, pre-commit-hook, lint-staged

I'm using `husky v4.3.0` `lint-staged 10.4.0` `prettier v2.1` on `create-react-app`.
package.json:

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{ts, tsx}": [
      "eslint  --fix",
      "git add"
    ],
    "src/**/*.{ts, tsx, css, md, mdx, html}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
```

I found a smiliar question [lint-staged not running on precommit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50048717/lint-staged-not-running-on-precommit), I tried the different answers mentioned such as:

- Delete the node modules and reinstall the packages
- Rebuild the packages with npm rebuild
- reinstall husky and lint-staged

Whenever I commit anything the lint-staged was not executed to run the lint and prettier.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the `git` version. I used `git v2.9.0` and husky v4 accepts `git >= 2.13.0`.

> Existing hooks are kept. Requires Node >= 10 and Git >= 2.13.0.

Reference: https://github.com/typicode/husky/tree/master