# How do I get `npx mrm lint-staged` working

Tags: yarnpkg, pre-commit-hook, npx, husky, lint-staged

I am aware of [lint-staged not running on precommit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50048717/lint-staged-not-running-on-precommit) but none of the solutions helped me.

I ran `npx mrm lint-staged`, but the pre-commit hook is not running. I went to check .git/hooks, and no hook was created here by husky. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling husky. Not sure if it matters, but I am using yarn as my package manager. Also not sure if it matters, but my npx is on version 6 instead of the version 10 (and I am unable to upgrade it, an issue I raised in another stackoverflow question).